# How do I make the second square with no spaces at the top of the page?

Tags: html, css

My first square is made with div tags and the second one is with ID which I named        #blacksquare2. The second square which is #blacksquare2 seems to always keep aligning at the bottom with my first square and can't bring it up to the page.Also the words 'i'm lovin' it' seem to be separate from each other. If it helps, I'm trying to achieve something like the McDonald's Website, just for practice.

```
CSS:
 div{
height:90px;
width:96px;
background-color:#CC0000;
border-radius:4px;
text-align:center;
margin-left:132px;
}
#blacksquare2{
height:25px;
width:200px;
background-color:#000000;
text-align:left;
margin:1px 10px 10px 10px
}   
#blacksquare2 a{
color:#E6E600;
font-size:11px;
font-family:Arial;
margin:25px
}
span{ 
font-size:50px; 
text-decoration:none;
font-family:Arial;
color:#E6E600;
font-weight:Arial;
margin-left:10px;
}
a{
text-decoration:none;
font-size:13px;
margin-right:10px;
color:white;
font-family:Arial bold;
}
l{
font-size:8px
}
body{
margin-top:0px
}


HTML:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Home :: McDonalds.com</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"; type="text/css"; href="McDonald'sPrac.css">
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <a href="http://www.mcdonalds.com/us/en/home.html"><span>M</span>i'm lovin'     it<l>™</l></a>
</div>
<div id="blacksquare2">
    <a href="http://www.mcdonalds.com/us/en/home.html#">Home<a>
</div>
</body>



</html>
```

Comment: Try adding `float:left` for both `div` and `#blacksquare2`

Comment: it goes left and right, that's not the problem. I just cant get the second square to the top, next to the first one. I tried using margin-bottom and margin-top.

Comment: Can you put your code in http://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: Styling default element (especially those which are very widely used - div) is a very bad practice. Do not have custom styles for universal tag `div`, use classes instead. Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors. Also you can go through any tutorials such as www.w3.org or the MDN site linked above

Comment: What about 'id' instead of 'class'? what is the difference? Should I use div only when making squares? Thanks in advance.

Comment: id identifies an element uniquely in a page. You can't have an id for more that one element in a page. A class is for creating and addressing a group of elements (all the elements with attribute `class='foo'` will be addressed when you do something with class, say styling elements or getting them in javascript). All the custom style you have added to `div` should be added to a class and that class name should be used in the HTML in the divs you need to style.

Answer (score 0):

Element `div` takes up all the available horizontal space by default.
You can use `span` instead of `div` for the first div. Also, setting

```
display: inline;
```

in css will have the same effect.

Comment: Why does it take all of the space if i used "margin-left" not "margin-right"? And if i already have a span in my html, would i be able to replace it with div id? what is display: inline;?

Comment: Your `span` doesn't take full horizontal space but it's wrapped in a div which does. Not specifying margin-right won't change the default behavior. Please read http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#edef-DIV. You can have ids for spans as well.

Answer (score 0):

For the text 'i'm lovin it' to be aligned properly you should not give any width for the div.

div is a block element and so will have the property to take the entire block.

Try giving `div{display:inline;}` in your css.

Comment: What exactly is display:inline? I was trying to give it width because I want to change the width of the square.